# Existe algo que compare o tipo do objeto?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quero testar o tipo do objeto não o valor dele, mais ou menos isto:

```
component1: IndexComponent

if(component1: IndexComponent) {
   dosomething();
}
```

Comment: Você sabe que votar em tudo no site, além de aceitar uma resposta nas suas perguntas? São coisas diferentes, pode fazer os dois.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provavelmente é isto que deseja:

```
if(component1 instanceof IndexComponent) {
   dosomething();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Instanceof.ts).

Então a variável precisa ter um objeto que seja do tipo especificado para a condição ser verdadeira. è possível verificar qualquer tipo que o objeto tenha, olhando inclusive na hierarquia dele.

[Documentação do operador `instanceof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards).

Em Javascript pode usar `typeof` mas acho que não é o que deseja.